# Google Maps API -What's the difference between using the Map API key vs the Plist API Key to access Maps

Tags: ios, firebase, google-maps

I'm using the Google Maps and Places API key in my iOS app.

When I hook firebase up to my app a plist file is created and an API key is generated for my project.

I then go to Google API Console > Library and enable the Google Maps and Google Places APIs. A credential key is created for both of them (separately).

For some reason when I went to the credentials page and kept reloading it the maps and places api keys weren't appearing so I decided to just try and use my firebase plist API key alone inside of my app and it let me access Maps and Places just fine using that alone.

Is there any loss or benefit to using the firebase plist api to access google maps/places as opposed to using the maps and places api keys?

```
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate, MessagingDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?

override init() {
    super.init()

    FirebaseApp.configure()

    let firebaseAPIKey = "qwerty..."

    GMSServices.provideAPIKey(firebaseAPIKey) // would normally be the maps api key
    GMSPlacesClient.provideAPIKey(firebaseAPIKey) // would normally be the places api key

    GMSPlacesClient.openSourceLicenseInfo()
    GMSServices.openSourceLicenseInfo()
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

}
```

I have another project where I use the firebase apiKey, maps api key, and places api all show on the credential page. I use the maps and places api key inside the this project. After the above scenario happened for my new project I went back to the other project and switched to using the firebase api key and everything works fine there also.